# Template for basic reusable button

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF (VS2013), I'm creating a button like so:

```
<Button>
  <Label>1</Label>
</Button>
```

Each of these buttons will have more to it, such as increased font size of the Label, grid row/column assignment, and I might use a binding for the label so that I can change the number. I'm creating a calculator app so I need to reuse this button 10 times (one for each number 0-9). Instead of copying/pasting this button XML 10 times, I wanted to see if I could templatize it.

I've read a little about ControlTemplate and DataTemplate, but I'm not sure if either of these are the correct thing to use. It's also not clear to me what should be a style or what should be a template.

So if someone could help me understand how to "templatize" the button and its styles (e.g. width, height, font size, etc) so that they can be easily reused, that would help a ton. Guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ControlTemplate` when you want to overwrite the entire template for a control, use a `DataTemplate` when you want to tell WPF how to draw a data object (usually the `DataContext`), and use `ContentTemplate` when you want to tell WPF how to draw the `Content` property of an object.

Creating a whole new `ControlTemplate` is quite complex. To demonstrate, check out [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example `ControlTemplate` for a `Button`.

In your case, I would recommend creating a `Style` for your button with setters for common properties such as `Height`, `Width`, `Font`, etc. If you want to draw your button's `Content` property in a custom way without completely overwriting the button template, include a `ContentTemplate` style setter  to tell WPF how to draw the `Button.Content` property.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CalculatorButton}" Content="1" />
```

and

```
<Style x:Key="CalculatorButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Foreground="Navy" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `ControlTemplate` defines how the button looks, the `ContentTemplate` defines how the `Button.Content` looks, and the `DataTemplate` used for the `ContentTemplate` is defining how the data object of "1" will be drawn.

Comment: This looks really good. Some questions: (1) Is `{Binding }` supposed to be empty? Does this tell it to look at the `Content` attribute specified when you add each button in the XAML? (2) Your last `Setter` specifies `Value=` and has another `<Setter.Value>` below it, is this a mistake?

Comment: Yes to both questions :) `{Binding }` is meant to be empty so it will simply display whatever the current data context is, which in this case is `Button.Content`, and I have a mistake in my example where I have set the `Value` property twice. I'll edit my answer to remove that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! And one last question... how did you know that `Button.Content` is the data context that it will refer to? I am not familiar with it's "search pattern" for such things.

Comment: @RobertDailey Hrmmm I probably first learned that via Google :) But it makes sense, a `ContentTemplate` is a template for the `.Content` property, and a `DataTemplate` is meant to tell WPF how to draw it's data layer, aka the `DataContext`. If you're new to WPF, you may be interested in reading a blog post of mine - [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). It explains a bit more about WPF's data layer vs its UI layer

Comment: One thing I can't figure out is how the parent's (Button) `DataContext`, when used as an object via `{Binding}` (no property specified), actually maps to `Button.Content`. This is what we set on each `<Button>` element, with the number. The default behavior is supposed to be that the Button's DataContext is NULL (since we don't set it on each Button), and that it will never find a datacontext since we never set one. I'm confused!

Comment: @RobertDailey I'm guessing that by default a `ContentTemplate` uses the `Content` property as the `DataContext`

Comment: That's the assumption I made but I couldn't find any official documentation of this behavior on MSDN, and I did a ton of searching :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Style of a button. Learning curve is not too steep, but the benefits are enormous. You can start learning about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx

Long story short: Open your project with Blend, right-click on your button, "Edit Style", "Edit a copy". If you choose to define it in Application, you can reuse it among other pages (it will be then in you App.xaml file)

Once you have the base style, edit it as much as you need.

Comment: Strangly I don't have an "Edit Style" option, only "Edit Template" which creates `<ControlTemplate>` instead of `<Style>` like I'd expect...

Comment: Also another issue... I simply want to create a template for a hierarchy of existing controls, I'm not changing the controls themselves. The template I want would literally just be placing the XML in-place, as a sort of meta-programming technique. However, I still want to use the stock Button and Label.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a copy of the style of the button. Use Blend (part of VS) to create that: open the context menu of the button inside the object tree, then select "Edit template" (or similar, don't have an english version at hand), then "Copy of template" (or alike).

Now you may change properties (in designer or XAML). Every button that shall have this style needs to reference this new ressource.